# What is behind Basecamp user experience design?

Tags: ajax, user-interface, user-experience, basecamp

Can any one tell what technologies are behind UX design of Basecamp? What makes its so rich UX on so simple UI? Is it just AJAX UX or a mix of more techs?

Comment: I think there is a video of design evaluation of Basecamp see that- http://vimeo.com/35600636

Comment: Thanks, I checked, Layout kept changing, but UX didn't I think

Comment: Its comprises of lots technology!!